Invalid python interpreter selected for the project
PyCharm не видит venv каталог, а берет уже каталог, который "не существует"(справа внизу путь), и переключатся никак не хочет на тот который мне нужен
пробовал добавить новый путь локального интерпретатора, не помогло

Нажимаете configure python interpreter и выбираете нужную вам версию python

не помогает, после выбора интерпретатора нажимаю Apply после чего оно автоматически обратно переключает на несуществующий

Тогда вы можете попробовать перейти в File>Settings>Project: (Ваш проект)>Python interpreter>Add interpreter, добавить там тот интерпретатор, который вам нужен и выбрать его

Попробовал, но все равно в пути появляется несуществующий каталог, проект расположен у меня по C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\pythonProject а venv берется из C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Project__Iport\pythonProject.venv\python.exe хотя на рабочем столе уже нету каталога Project__Iport, в списке интерпретаторов отображается еще какой-то C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Hmmsim\DiscordBot.venv\python.exe но при его выборе тоже берется несуществующий C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Project__Iport\pythonProject.venv\python.exe

Звучит очень странно. В таком случае ничем помочь не смогу :( .Можете попробовать переустановить pycharm или создать venv, который он требует ( C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Project__Iport\pythonProject.venv\python.exe)

Попробуйте удалить папку venv и также папку pythonCache, после этого заново пересоздайте venv с нужными параметрами, и должно все заработать.
